# cell background color is not changing when we reload the tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, background-color

I have a tableview and when I select one cell I am changing the backgroup color of that cell to identify the selected row.

My problem is: I am reloading the table view when I select the next row, at this time I am unable to change the background color of that cell.

I wrote the below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if (m_selectedCell == indexPath.row) {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your code just before you return cell. and also check the m_selectedCell assigns or nil?

if value is match then add a UIImageView with background color in cell.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the cell's background color has to be performed in the `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. This message is sent after the cell is created, but before it is drawn on screen.

Comment: Should be there instead of CellFor?

Answer (score 1):

you write this code in cellForRowAtIndex Method:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this code in DidSelectRowIndexPath itself.

```
if (m_selectedCell == indexPath.row) {
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply, to try this code in DidSelectRowIndexPath method i am not clicking on cell to select next cell, here once i select one cell than the view is going to Next View, from that next view i am swiping to go to next cell, once i am swiping i am reloading my first view to change the selected cell background color.

Comment: if u want to change background color when select on tableview cell u need to give in didselectRowIndexPath only.Can u tell me onething when u click a cell is it navigate or not?

Comment: Yes it is navigating but only for the first time DidSelectRow method will call and from the second time i am operating from another view and trying to reload first view

Comment: actually is selecting one cell it navigates to another view. then click on back button you can move to first view. Don't scared about this. In first view. u want background color for cell selecting you give in didselectrowindexpath. by this. if select the cell it will change background color. or if you want background color when select on cell you give <b>HeighlightedbackgroundColor</b>. I think you will get answer by this. If like it accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the above code out of this loop called `if(cell==nil)`